# Join Issue in Teradata

Tags: sql, join, logic, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have 2 fields in 2 tables .ie. status  (status VARCHAR(80) CHARACTER SET LATIN CASESPECIFIC)
One table has 1000 status as value is 'success'
2nd table has 1 value for status=success and other values like 'failure'. I want to join 2 tables and get the value from 2nd table (dw_status_id)

1ST TABLE scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test

```
STATUS    |  any_number
success   |    67
success   |    1
success   |    2
success   |    3
success   |    42
success   |    52
failure   |    45
```

2nd table scratch.dw_job_status_dim_test

```
status   |dw_status_id
failure  |34      
success  |12
running  |45
```

Result :-

```
Status    |  dw_status_id
success   |    12
success   |    12
success   |    12
success   |    12
success   |    12
success   |    12
failure   |    34
```

Query I am using  :-

```
sel b.dw_status_id from scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test a
join scratch.dw_job_status_dim_test b on trim(a.status)=trim(b.status)
```

Actual result =0

It would be very great if any one can help to achieve this

Thanks

Comment: Unless there are leading spaces there's  no need to join using Trim. But when you don't get any results it  might indicate that either the 'success'  strings are not exactly the same (column is definied as *casespecific*) or there might be some trailing chharacters which only look like a space. Do you get a result when you apply `where status = 'success'` against both tables individually?

Comment: no dnoeth..-> select  scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test.status, dw_job_status_id 
from scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test, scratch.dw_job_status_dim_test 
where scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test.status like  '%success%' 
and scratch.dw_job_status_dim_test.status = 'success';         This is working.. But I don't want to hardcode it.

Comment: What if you run it without wildcards: `status = 'success'`?

Comment: Result would be no row

Comment: and using above query result would be   success,12 success,12, success 12

Comment: Try `Select CHAR2HEXINT(status) ... WHERE status like 'success%'   and char_length(status)  <>7` to check if there's some invisible characters after 'success'

Comment: Tried this :_ Select CHAR2HEXINT(status) from scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test Result :- 737563636573730D

Comment: Tried this for other table Select CHAR2HEXINT(status) from  scratch.dw_job_status_dim_test Result for success :- 73756363657373

Comment: Tried this :- Select CHAR2HEXINT(status)  from scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test  WHERE status like 'success%' and char_length(status) <>7 Result :- 737563636573730D

Comment: Tried this Select CHAR2HEXINT(status)  from scratch.dw_job_status_dim_test   WHERE status like '%success%' and char_length(status) <>7 Result :- Nothing

Comment: There's a trailing `0D`, linebreak. Probably not loaded correctly, you can get rid of them using `TRIM(TRAILING '0D'xc FROM status)`

Comment: Thanks a lot again dnoeth.. It worked

Comment: Always appreciate your help

Comment: You should communicate that, they should fix the loading process

Comment: Yes sure... Will do that

Comment: One more thing, If the input will not have 0D .. Can we make it generalised it may be the trailing character would have 0E -> HOw can we modify this query then : select  scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test.status, dw_job_status_id 
from scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test, scratch.dw_job_status_dim_test 
where TRIM(TRAILING '0D'xc FROM scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test.status)  = scratch.dw_job_status_dim_test.status

Comment: This also working :- select a.status, b.dw_job_status_id 
from scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test a
inner join scratch.dw_job_status_dim_test b on a.status like b.status||'%'

Comment: Yes, but the plan will be very inefficient (=*product join*). If you know those possible characters in advance (probably 0D & 0A) you can utilize RTRIM to get rid them all. Otherwise you should be able to write a Regular Expression to extract what you want

Comment: Could you please have a look once :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49174837/implement-aggregation-in-teradata

Answer (score 2):

You only have to select the status from scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test and the dw_status_id from scratch.dw_job_status_dim_test. And you have to check if the status of both tables equals success.

So I've tried this on my own, maybe it helps:

```
select distinct scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test.status, dw_status_id 
from scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test, scratch.dw_job_status_dim_test 
where scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test.status = scratch.dw_job_status_dim_test.status
```

Comment: I have added my comment alex if it helps

Comment: I have updated you query with like then it is returning result

Comment: Still zero results

Comment: Maybe one of my fields i used in my query are not equal to the fields you used in your database. Or you try it with like instead of =

Comment: By using like to %success%.. that i don't want to hardcode it..Is it possible to use like with all status from cogif 1st table ?

Comment: Could you please have a look once here :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49174837/implement-aggregation-in-teradata

Answer (score 0):

These are 3 records from first table :-

ship by date on time metrics-superrush  0   0   0   0   2018-03-07 01:40:08 2018-03-07 00:00:00 2018-03-07 01:41:46.917000  1.64101666667   success

lab - late shipment details 0   0   0   0   2018-03-07 01:40:08 2018-03-07 00:00:00 2018-03-07 01:40:44.950000  0.6078  success

shipping upgrade-tp/wpd/mypub   0   0   0   0   2018-03-07 01:40:09 2018-03-07 00:00:00 2018-03-07 01:40:25.028000  0.2674  success

These are some records from 2nd table

dw_status_id status description success_indicator

10  running RUNNING 0

11  stopped STOPPED 0

12  success SUCCESS 1

I have tried your 2 queries.. both are giving no results.
Ideally it should give the desired result. But somehow we are mistaking in join or varchar case specific ..PLease let me know if you are having more thought where i am doing mistake

Comment: This updated sql giving the result :-                                              
                                  select distinct scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test.status, dw_job_status_id 
from scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test, scratch.dw_job_status_dim_test 
where scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test.status like  '%success%' 
and scratch.dw_job_status_dim_test.status = 'success';

Comment: Result :- success  12

Comment: So this query works for you? I think it's the same like the one i posted above. The only difference is that you wrote 'like' instead of '='.

Comment: Yes Alex..But I don't want to hardcode success... I want all the status records from first table cogipf ..It may be I will get other status like failure as well in future ..

Comment: I hope you are getting me

Comment: I have updated my original post which may help to understand clearly

Comment: I've edited my answer, maybe this query shows the result you want.

Comment: Somehow both are not equal  : scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test.status = scratch.dw_job_status_dim_test.status