# Implement aggregation in Teradata

Tags: group-by, aggregate-functions, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I want to aggregate 2 fields proct_dt, dw_job_id in ascendinng order
My scenario would be clear by using below queries and result.

First query :-

sel * from scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test1 order by proct_dt,dw_job_id where dw_job_id =10309

Output :-

```
dw_job_id   proct_dt           start_ts          end_ts                      time_diff
```

1   10,309  2018-03-06 00:00:00 2018-03-06 07:04:18 2018-03-06 07:04:22.457000  0
2   10,309  2018-03-06 00:00:00 2018-03-06 06:58:50 2018-03-06 06:58:51.029000  0
3   10,309  2018-03-07 00:00:00 2018-03-07 06:35:36 2018-03-07 06:36:03.809000  1
4   10,309  2018-03-06 00:00:00 2018-03-06 07:00:35 2018-03-06 07:00:40.702000  0

5   10,309  2018-03-06 00:00:00 2018-03-06 06:30:25 2018-03-06 06:30:42.759000  0

6   10,309  2018-03-06 00:00:00 2018-03-06 07:10:27 2018-03-06 07:10:28.715000  0

7   10,309  2018-03-06 00:00:00 2018-03-06 06:59:44 2018-03-06 06:59:48.315000  0

8   10,309  2018-03-06 00:00:00 2018-03-06 07:00:15 2018-03-06 07:00:15.086000  0

9   10,309  2018-03-06 00:00:00 2018-03-06 07:04:02 2018-03-06 07:04:02.925000  0

2nd Query :-

sel * from scratch.fact_test order by proct_dt asc ,dw_job_id asc where dw_job_id =10309

Result :-

```
dw_job_id   proct_dt            start_ts              end_ts      status
```

1   10,309  2018-03-06 00:00:00 2018-03-06 06:30:25 2018-03-06 06:30:42.759 12

2   10,309  2018-03-07 00:00:00 2018-03-07 06:35:36 2018-03-07 06:36:03.809 12

So here in the 2nd query I got the desire result as from 1st table by having first occurrence of proct_dt,start_ts,end_ts

Please let me know for any clarification
It would be very great if anyone can help to achieve this case.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you want from your explanation, but it looks like you want to get the first run of a job per day, which is easy using a Row_Number:

```
select * 
from scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test1
where dw_job_id =10309
qualify
   row_number()
   over (partition by dw_job_id, proc_dt -- for each job & date
         order by start_ts) = 1          -- only the 1st run
```

Comment: @HimanshuPant: Move the Row_Number into the Select list and run it without the Qualify and you'll see how the ranking is assigned

Comment: Thanks dnoeth for all your help

Comment: :- Please have a look once :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191484/calculate-time-difference-in-teradata