# Calculate time difference in Teradata

Tags: datetime, timestamp, left-join, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a scenario to calculate difference of timestamp in minute. There is one common field in 2 tables i.e dw_job_id
 and want to join 2 tables and guessing, calculate

```
(scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test2.end_ts - concat(proct_dt, scratch.dw_job_sla_dim_test.sla_time)
```

Example, Subtraction in minute:

```
(2018-03-05 01:53:14.201000 - 2018-03-05 08:00:00.000000)= -366
```

It would be quite clear using below records:

1st query has end_ts:

```
sel * from scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test2 where  dw_job_id=1226
```

Result:

```
dw_job_id   proct_dt              start_ts              end_ts                 time_diff    dw_job_status_id    
1,226       2018-03-05 00:00:00   2018-03-05 01:50:23   2018-03-05 01:53:14.201000  3            12                                                                    
1,226       2018-03-06 00:00:00   2018-03-06 01:42:56   2018-03-06 01:45:23.553000  3            12
```

2nd query :

```
select * from scratch.dw_job_sla_dim_test  where dw_job_id=1226
```

Result:

```
dw_job_id   sla_hour    sla_minute   sla_time
1,226       8             0           08:00:00.000000
```

Final result should be:

```
 dw_job_id  run_date       start_timestamp               end_timestamp           runtime_minutes      sla_miss_minutes

  1,226     3/5/2018    3/5/2018 01:50:23.000000    3/5/2018 01:53:14.201000       2                     -366   
  1,226     3/6/2018    3/6/2018 01:42:56.000000    3/6/2018 01:45:23.553000       2                     -374
```

Example:

Subtraction in minute :-(2018-03-05 01:53:14.201000 - 2018-03-05 08:00:00.000000)= -366

Data types:

```
  sla_hour INTEGER,
  sla_minute INTEGER,
  sla_time TIME(6),
  end_ts VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
```

Comment: `cast(start_ts as time)` extracts the time portion, now join to the SLA table and `cast(start_ts as time) - sla_time minute(4)` returns the difference

Comment: Trying this :- select cast(a.end_ts as time) - sla_time minute(4)  from scratch.COGIPF_RUNREPORT_test2 a left outer join scratch.dw_job_sla_dim_test b on b.dw_job_id=a.dw_job_id  where a.dw_job_id=1226  ;      but getting invalid time

Comment: @dnoeth Above one is the wrong query.. because it doesn't have 2018-03-05 before sla_time

Comment: Hi, Any heads up on this..? Please have a look once

Comment: According to your example `sla_time` is a `TIME`, thus the difference calculation should work, what's the exact error message? `sla_time` needs no date part, because both `start_ts` and `sla_time` will be from the same date.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following logic in the past. But I think its what you are after.

```
,(CAST((CAST(end_timestamp AS DATE)- CAST(start_timestamp AS DATE)) AS DECIMAL(18,6)) * 60*24)
  + ((EXTRACT(  HOUR FROM end_timestamp) - EXTRACT(  HOUR FROM start_timestamp))* 60)
  + ((EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM end_timestamp) - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM start_timestamp))  )
  + ((EXTRACT(SECOND FROM end_timestamp) - EXTRACT(SECOND FROM start_timestamp))/60)
AS "Difference in Minutes"
```

For others I will include my hours and seconds calculations as well

```
,(CAST((CAST(end_timestamp AS DATE)- CAST(start_timestamp AS DATE)) AS DECIMAL(18,6)) * 60*60*24)
  + ((EXTRACT(  HOUR FROM end_timestamp) - EXTRACT(  HOUR FROM start_timestamp))* 60*60)
  + ((EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM end_timestamp) - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM start_timestamp)) * 60)
  + ((EXTRACT(SECOND FROM end_timestamp) - EXTRACT(SECOND FROM start_timestamp)))
AS "Difference in Seconds"  


,(CAST((CAST(end_timestamp AS DATE)- CAST(start_timestamp AS DATE)) AS DECIMAL(18,6)) * 24)
  + ((EXTRACT(  HOUR FROM end_timestamp) - EXTRACT(  HOUR FROM start_timestamp)))
  + ((EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM end_timestamp) - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM start_timestamp)) / 60.000000)
  + ((EXTRACT(SECOND FROM end_timestamp) - EXTRACT(SECOND FROM start_timestamp)) / 3600.000000)
AS "Difference In Hours"
```