# Teradata timestamp subtraction with difference in minutes

Tags: sql, teradata

```
select StartDatetime,EndDatetime,
(TRIM((COALESCE(CAST((CAST(EndDatetime AS TIME) - CAST(StartDatetime AS TIME) MINUTE(4)) AS INT),'')))) as TimeDiff
From Table1
```

`EndDatetime` and `StartDatetime` are columns of type `Timestamp(6)`. The above query gave the difference in between the timestamps in minutes. It is working if both the timestamps are present in the same day. But when `EndDatetime` is having a value of tomorrow wrt to the `StartDatetime` then the TimeDiff value that is being returned is a negative value. Using absolute function is not a best solution because then the TimeDiff number itself isn't accurate.

How to get the timestamp difference precisely in minutes?

Comment: Why are you doing these casts?  CAST(EndDatetime AS TIME) - CAST(StartDatetime AS TIME)  .... by casting the TIMESTAMP value (which contains your date + time info) to TIME, then the related date will be lost.  I suspect you will need to do something similar to what is described here (https://downloads.teradata.com/forum/database/timestamp-difference-in-minutes-without-using-periods) or here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191484/calculate-time-difference-in-teradata).  Sorry, I'm not a regular Teradata user myself, otherwise I might be able to answer the question directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way by using extract :

```
Select 
    StartDatetime,EndDatetime
    ,(CAST((CAST(EndDatetime AS DATE)- CAST(StartDatetime AS DATE)) AS DECIMAL(18,6)) * 60*24)
    + ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM EndDatetime) - EXTRACT(HOUR FROM StartDatetime))* 60)
    + ((EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM EndDatetime) - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM StartDatetime)))
    + ((EXTRACT(SECOND FROM EndDatetime) - EXTRACT(SECOND FROM StartDatetime))/60)
AS "Difference in Minutes"
from Table1
```